# Failed to use flexbox to stretch to full page height

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to use flexbox for a full page lay-out, but when there isn't enough text in the main area, it isn't stretched vertically to fill the remaining space of the page as I expected.

It behaves like I specified `align-content: space-between`, but I didn't. What am I doing wrong here?

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: stretch;
  /* no effect here  */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
body > #header-area {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  order: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
body > #menu-area {
  flex: 0 0 180px;
  order: 2;
}
body > #main-area {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  order: 3;
}
body > #aside-area {
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  order: 4;
}
body > #footer-area {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  order: 5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-area" style="background-color: aqua">
  main area
</div>

<div id="menu-area" style="background-color: lavender">
  menu area
</div>

<div id="aside-area" style="background-color: lemonchiffon">
  sidebar area
</div>

<div id="header-area" style="background-color: lightsteelblue">
  header area
</div>

<div id="footer-area" style="background-color: lightskyblue">
  footer area
</div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can't do this without setting the `body` to `flex-direction: column` AND using additional wrapping elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can wrap your middle content, then I would do it like this

```css
html {height:100%;} /* add this */
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%; /* change this to min-height */
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}
body > #header-area {
  /* flex: 1 1 auto; -  not sure what this is for so I have removed it */
  order: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
#menu-area {
  flex: 0 0 180px;
  order:1;
}
#main-area {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  order:2;
}
#aside-area {
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  order:3;
}
body > #footer-area {
  /* flex: 1 1 auto; -  not sure what this is for so I have removed it */
  order: 3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
#content {
  flex-direction:row;
  display:flex;
  flex-grow:1;
  order:2;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="main-area" style="background-color: aqua">
    main area
  </div>

  <div id="menu-area" style="background-color: lavender">
    menu area
  </div>

  <div id="aside-area" style="background-color: lemonchiffon">
    sidebar area
  </div>
</div>

<div id="header-area" style="background-color: lightsteelblue">
  header area
</div>

<div id="footer-area" style="background-color: lightskyblue">
  footer area
</div>
```

Comment: I was hoping that the additional wrapper (#content) wasn't needed, so that I could easily change the display order for different screen sizes (by using flex-flow: row wrap; on the container and flex order: in the items). But the additional wrapper seems to make this impossible.

Comment: @Paul  it may be possible, I'm just starting to learn flex and have seen it do a lot more than I am able to make it do.  I seem to remember ages ago that I saw something like you were asking for  but can't remember if they used a wrapper or not.  After a bit of searching though, most of the examples I have come across use a wrapper for the middle content

Comment: Yes, I've been looking too, of course. But all the examples where that's done, are trivially simple and don't have that extra wrapper and use flex-flow: row wrap. If I find a solution I will post it here...